# Input type number not updating value on enter

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

`App` holds an input element that updates on enter, on blur and on the next button click. When I inspect the element in dev tools, the `value` attribute updates on both blur and next button click, but never on the enter.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

interface IAppProps {
  InputVal: number;
  onEnter: (num: number) => void;
}

const Parent: React.FC = () => {
  const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = React.useState(1);
  const grabVal = (val: number) => {
    console.log("New value::", val);
    setCurrentValue(val);
  };

  return <App InputVal={currentValue} onEnter={grabVal} />;
};

const App: React.FC<IAppProps> = ({ InputVal, onEnter }) => {
  const inputRef: any = React.createRef();
  const handleEnterKey = (e: any) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      onEnter(Number((e.target as HTMLInputElement).value));
    }
  };

  const nextClick = (e: any) => {
    inputRef.current.value = InputVal + 1;
    onEnter(InputVal + 1);
  };

  const blurry = (e: any) => {
    onEnter(Number(e.target.value));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="number"
        onKeyUp={handleEnterKey}
        ref={inputRef}
        defaultValue={InputVal as any}
        onBlur={blurry}
      />
      <button onClick={nextClick}>Next</button>
    </>
  );
};

render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

How can I get it to update on enter click?

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-7bkl7

Answer (score 1):

what do you want to update?

The code is working how it should in theory, but when you do a keyup call and in the event handler all you are doing is console logging the value and setting it to the new state.

THe only way to increment the number now in in the next method call.

```
 <input
        type="number"
        onKeyUp={handleEnterKey}
        ref={inputRef}
        defaultValue={InputVal as any}
        onBlur={blurry}
        value={InputVal as number}
      />
```

Comment: I want to see the value attribute being updated on enter, the way it is being updated onBlur and next button click.

Comment: onBlur doesnt do anything except trigger the console.log in the parent, the only reason the button click is updating the UI in the child is that you are explicitily setting the value on line 30, remove that      inputRef.current.value = InputVal + 1;
 and the UI wont update.  Have a look at the value attribute for the input element

Comment: With your code you can't type anything into the field.

Comment: See my `blurry` func, its doing the same as `handleEnterKey`, but when `blurry` fires, it actually updates the `value` attribute of input. Just inspect the element in dev tools. It doesn't do that for `handleEnterKey`

Comment: Im pretty sure the cause of your issues is the use of defaultValue vs value.

Comment: I have to use defaultValue because with value, you need an onChange event, which I do not want. I only want the values to change on enter, blur and next button click.

Comment: just use it as a jumping off point. the enter method is working, dont update the state of the child component using the `inputRef.current.value = InputVal + 1;`

Comment: Yes it is firing the right event. But screen readers will have difficulty since in the DOM the input's value is not reflecting the firing of the event.

Comment: input is like another child component, its api is thru the methods we can use on it - ie onChange, value, etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194372/discussion-between-zerodarkthirty-and-sten-muchow).

Comment: Im just killing some time at work right now, dont have too much more time.